# Akasha on Normal Internet?

Tags: network, resolver, akasha

Is it possible to have the Akasha platform accessible on normal internet / intractable via simple URL?

Congratulations to all Akasha developers, I hear very positive reviews so far! : ) One possible hinderance to main stream adoption however is having to install a .exe/.dmg or program to interact. Would be great if users could access content on regular internet by registering/syncing their accounts/profiles online instead.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it is not possible. But soon we can expect it to work through mist browser or through metamask addon on Chrome. 
I will keep an eye on it and keep this answer updated

Comment: appreciated mate : ) would be great future technical achievement for other DApps too, whether it be from some sort of Portal or data Relay akin to blockchain explorers. Although given the censorship resistant properties, perhaps users can elect to publish their content to public web, certainly would be disruptive for advertising/marketing